# dart angular2 - validate number in form

Tags: forms, validation, angular, dart

Is there a builtin validator in Angular2 to validate a number input? The attributes "min" and "max" do not seem to be interpreted by the validator.

Thanks for your help.

My input in my template :

```
<input id="nbLuggage" name="nbLuggage" classe="form-control"
       type="number" min="1" max="15" 
       [(ngModel)]="form.nbLuggage" ngControl="nbLuggage" required>
```

If I enter "20", my input still is "ng-valid".

I use angular2: 2.0.0-beta.21.

Comment: Please post the code that demonstrates what you tried.

Comment: I think `min` and `max` should work this way, but I haven't tried since quite some time. What Angular2 version are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, but you can create your own, something like this

```
const NUMBER_VALIDATOR = const Provider(NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: NumberValidator, multi: true);

@Directive(
    selector:
    "input[type=number][ngControl],input[type=number][ngFormControl],input[type=number][ngModel])",
    providers: const [NUMBER_VALIDATOR])
class NumberValidator implements Validator {
  ValidatorFn _validator;

  NumberValidator(@Attribute("min") String minStr, @Attribute("max") String maxStr) {
    final num min = minStr == null ? null : num.parse(minStr);
    final num max = maxStr == null ? null : num.parse(maxStr);
    this._validator = NumberValidators.minMaxNumberValidator(min, max);
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> validate(AbstractControl c) {
    return this._validator(c);
  }
}

abstract class NumberValidators {
  NumberValidators._();

  static ValidatorFn minMaxNumberValidator(num min, num max) {
    return (AbstractControl control) {
      if (Validators.required(control) != null) {
        return null;
      }
      final num value = control.value;
      if (value != null) {
        if (min != null && value < min) {
          return {"min": {"required": min, "actual": value}};
        }
        if (max != null && value > max) {
          return {"max": {"required": max, "actual": value}};
        }
      }
      return null;
    };
  }
}
```

And then you should add `NumberValidator` to your component's `directives` list.
Also, if you want to bind variables to `min` and `max`, you need not just to pass values into constructor, but re-initialize `_validator` callback on each `min` and `max` attribute set. And in fact may be better to split it to two separate validators (in my case there is also `step` validator, that can not work separately).